# GEE Sentinel-2 Active Fire Detection - conditional image composition

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, sentinel-2, digital-image-processing

I am working on Sentinel-2 image fire detection in Google Earth Engine. I would like to apply the Custom Scripts Active Fire Detection algorithm (https://github.com/sentinel-hub/custom-scripts/tree/master/sentinel-2/active_fire_detection) in GEE:

```
var NGDR = index(B02, B03);
var Inverse = (B02 - 0.2) / (0.5 - 0.2);
//Fire indicator
var SAHM_INDEX= ((B12 - B11) / (B12 + B11));

if (Inverse > 1) { 
    return [0.5 * B04, 0.5 * B03, 20 * B02 ];
}

if (Inverse > 0 && NGDR>0) { 
    return [0.5 * B04  , 0.5 * B03, 20 * B02];
}

if((SAHM_INDEX>0.4)||(B12>1)){
  return[20*B04, 1*B03, 1*B02];
}

else {
 return [B04,B04,B04]
}
```

I already wrote a function in GEE that calculates the indexes:

```
// A function to compute Index.
var Indexy = function(image) {
  var NDGR = image.expression(
      'float(Bd2 - Bd3) / (Bd2 + Bd3)',
      {
        'Bd2': image.select('B2'),
        'Bd3': image.select('B3')
      }).rename('NDGR');
      
  var Inverse = image.expression(
      'float(Bd2 - L) / (M - L)',
      {
        'Bd2': image.select('B2'),
        'Bd3': image.select('B3'),
        'L': 0.2,
        'M': 0.5
      }).rename('Inverse');
      
    var SAHM_INDEX = image.expression(
      'float(Bd12 - Bd11) / (Bd12 + Bd11)',
      {
        'Bd12': image.select('B12'),
        'Bd11': image.select('B11')
      }).rename('SAHM_INDEX');
 return image.addBands(NDGR).addBands(Inverse).addBands(SAHM_INDEX);
};
```

but i have problem with applying conditional statements inside the expression(). I tried to use 'image.where()' and expression() using '?' and it doesnt worked. Would you please help me to resolve the problem?